# Laravel Eloquent - text field with leading number getting interpreted as integer

Tags: laravel, text, casting, eloquent, integer

I have the following code:

```
    $event = Event::where('slug', '=', $param)
        ->orWhere('eventID', '=', $param)
        ->firstOrFail();
```

The purpose is to enable $event to populate either with its id or a short text string in the slug field.

I'm experiencing an issue where text beginning with a number is causes the $event to get the value where eventID = the numeric part of the text.

This is not the desired behavior.

Ideas?  Thanks!

Comment: You have added orWhere in condition

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need check `$param` for integer value and depends on that make a query. It easy to do with `when` method for **laravel versions > 5.3**. For older version logic will be the same but don't use `when` method because it has not third parameter.

```
$event = Event::when(filter_var($param, FILTER_VALIDATE_INT) !== false,
       function($query) use ($param){
           return $query->where('eventID', $param);
       },
       function($query) use ($param){
           return $query->where('slug', $param);
       }
       )->firstOrFail();
```

Other way:

```
$event = Event::query();
$event = filter_var($param, FILTER_VALIDATE_INT) !== false ? $event->where('eventID', $param) : $event->where('slug', $param);
$event = $event->firstOrFail();
```